# Filter multiple parameters with MongoDB provider

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the below document schema.

```
{
      "name":"Name",
      "region":"New Jersey",
      "address":"92 Something Rd",
      "city":"Jersey City",
      "state":"NJ",
      "zipCode":"07302",
      "country":"USA",
      amenities":[
         "Sauna",
         "Locker",
         "Shop"
      ],
      "services":[
         "Car Rental",
         "Transportation"
      ]
}
```

I want with one call to the server to get all the documents matching any of the filter arguments where map 1-1 meaning `"state" = "NJ" OR "city" = "Jersey City"` but also when any value of the list contained to any document array child, example `[ "Sauna", "Locker" ] ANY IN "amenities"`. And it should be an OR concatenation of all the possible filters.

Using the C# MongoDB Driver I came up with the below methods so far in a `MongoRepository` class but doesn't return the desired results.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> DocumentsMatchEqFieldValueAsync<T>(string collectionName,
            IDictionary<string, string> fieldsValues = null,
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> fieldsWithEnumerableValues = null,
            IEnumerable<ObjectId> ids = null)
{
    var cursor = await GetEqAsyncCursor<T>(collectionName, fieldsValues, fieldsWithEnumerableValues, ids).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await cursor.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

protected Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> GetEqAsyncCursor<T>(string collectionName, 
            IDictionary<string, string> fieldsValues = null,
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> fieldsWithEnumerableValues = null,
            IEnumerable<ObjectId> ids = null)
{
    var collection = GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    var builder = Builders<T>.Filter;

    // Not sure if this is the correct way to initialize it because it seems adding an empty filter condition returning ALL document;
    FilterDefinition<T> filter = new BsonDocument(); 

    if (fieldsValues != null &&
        fieldsValues.Any())
    {
        filter = filter | fieldsValues
                    .Select(p => builder.Eq(p.Key, p.Value))
                    .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2);
    }

    if (fieldsWithEnumerableValues != null &&
        fieldsWithEnumerableValues.Any())
    {
        filter = filter | fieldsWithEnumerableValues
                    .Select(p => builder.AnyEq(p.Key, p.Value))
                    .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2);
    }

    if (ids != null &&
        ids.Any())
    {
        filter = filter | ids
                .Select(p => builder.Eq("_id", p))
                .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2);
    }
    return collection.FindAsync(filter);
}
```

I want it to be generic so the client can call the method like this.

```
public async Task should_return_any_records_matching_all_possible_criteria()
{
    // Arrange
    IDocumentRepository documentRepository = new MongoRepository(_mongoConnectionString, _mongoDatabase);

    // Act
    var documents = await documentRepository.DocumentsMatchEqFieldValueAsync<BsonDocument>(Courses,
                fieldsValues: new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "state", "NJ" },
                    { "city", "Jersey City" }
                },
                fieldsWithEnumerableValues: new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "services", new List<string> { "Car Rental", "Locker" } },
                    { "amenities", new List<string> { "Sauna", "Shop" } }
                });

    // Assert
    documents.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
}
```

I would expect documents that have `"state" = "NJ" OR "city" = "Jersey City" OR "services" CONTAINS ANY OF "Car Rental", "Locker" OR "amenities" CONTAINS ANY OF "Sauna", "Shop"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am posting below the method I ended up using after some research for the future help of anyone looking to do the same. I found how to query using regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033905/122769), write plain MongoDB queries and add them to the filter collection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722788/122769), and how to debug the generated query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732004/122769).

After having all this information and a little bit of experimentation using the Studio 3T client find below the method.

```
protected Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> GetEqAsyncCursor<T>(string collectionName,
            IDictionary<string, string> fieldEqValue = null,
            IDictionary<string, string> fieldContainsValue = null,
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> fieldEqValues = null,
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> fieldElemMatchInValues = null,
            IEnumerable<ObjectId> ids = null)
{
    var collection = GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    var builder = Builders<T>.Filter;

    IList<FilterDefinition<T>> filters = new List<FilterDefinition<T>>();

    if (fieldEqValue != null &&
        fieldEqValue.Any())
    {
        filters.Add(fieldEqValue
                    .Select(p => builder.Eq(p.Key, p.Value))
                    .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2));
    }

    if (fieldContainsValue != null &&
        fieldContainsValue.Any())
    {
        filters.Add(fieldContainsValue
                    .Select(p => builder.Regex(p.Key, new BsonRegularExpression($".*{p.Value}.*", "i")))
                    .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2));
    }

    if (fieldEqValues != null &&
        fieldEqValues.Any())
    {
        foreach (var pair in fieldEqValues)
        {
            foreach (var value in pair.Value)
            {
                filters.Add(builder.Eq(pair.Key, value));
            }
        }
    }

    if (fieldElemMatchInValues != null &&
        fieldElemMatchInValues.Any())
    {
        var baseQuery = "{ \"%key%\": { $elemMatch: { $in: [%values%] } } }";
        foreach (var item in fieldElemMatchInValues)
        {
            var replaceKeyQuery = baseQuery.Replace("%key%", item.Key);
            var bsonQuery = replaceKeyQuery.Replace("%values%", 
                        item.Value
                            .Select(p => $"\"{p}\"")
                            .Aggregate((value1, value2) => $"{value1},
 {value2}"));
            var filter = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bsonQuery);
            filters.Add(filter);
        }
    }

    if (ids != null &&
        ids.Any())
    {
        filters.Add(ids
                .Select(p => builder.Eq("_id", p))
                .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1 | p2));
    }

    var filterConcat = builder.Or(filters);

    // Here's how you can debug the generated query
    //var documentSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
    //var renderedFilter = filterConcat.Render(documentSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry).ToString();

    return collection.FindAsync(filterConcat);
}
```